# tfjs-node on old cpu (without AVX)

Tags: tensorflow, tfjs-node

There is a desire to do the initial steps in tfjs using nodejs. At the moment, for tests, I can only use a computer with the following configuration:
Windows 7 SP1
8Gb Ram
e7500 (no AVX)
GeForce 750Ti
node v12.19.0

When using tfjs-node, I get the error:

```
return process.dlopen (module, path.toNamespacedPath (filename));
```

As far as I understand this is due to the fact that the processor is very old, without AVX.
Can I somehow rebuild tfjs-node to work on my processor, it would be ideal to build tfjs-node-gpu. If there is such an opportunity, what should I do for this?

I've come across assemblies from fo40225 (https://github.com/fo40225), but they are for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved a problem.
First I tried changing Windows to Win10, it didn't help.
Therefore, I decided to rebuild tensorflow.dll. After many attempts, I came up with this setup:
Basel 3.1
Python 3.8
NumPy installed globally
VS BuildTools 2019
Tensorflow branch 2.3 compiled (bazel build -c opt // tensorflow / tools / lib_package: libtensorflow)

After that I copied the dll to the folder with node_modules \ @tensorflow \ tfjs-node \ lib \ napi-v6